# Compile libconfig++ program

Tags: c++, makefile, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, libconfig

I downloaded libconfig-1.4.9 on ubuntu 16.04.1LTS

```
http://igor-zivkovic.from.hr/BLFS/general/libconfig.html
```

and installed. Examples which were included in lib passed successfully.
I copied example1 to another directory. Compile

```
g++ example1.cpp -lconfig++ -Wall -o example1
```

Successfull.
Run

```
./example1: symbol lookup error: ./example1: undefined symbol: _ZNK9libconfig7SettingcvSsEv
```

I copied this example to another computer and example was working fine (libconfig was installed earlier with sudo apt-get install (ubuntu 14.04LTS)).

example1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <libconfig.h++>

using namespace std;
using namespace libconfig;

// This example reads the configuration file 'example.cfg' and displays
// some of its contents.

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Config cfg;

  // Read the file. If there is an error, report it and exit.
  try
  {
    cfg.readFile("example.cfg");
  }
  catch(const FileIOException &fioex)
  {
    std::cerr << "I/O error while reading file." << std::endl;
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  catch(const ParseException &pex)
  {
    std::cerr << "Parse error at " << pex.getFile() << ":" << pex.getLine()
              << " - " << pex.getError() << std::endl;
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Get the store name.
  try
  {
    string name = cfg.lookup("name");
    cout << "Store name: " << name << endl << endl;
  }
  catch(const SettingNotFoundException &nfex)
  {
    cerr << "No 'name' setting in configuration file." << endl;
  }

  const Setting& root = cfg.getRoot();

  // Output a list of all books in the inventory.
  try
  {
    const Setting &books = root["inventory"]["books"];
    int count = books.getLength();

    cout << setw(30) << left << "TITLE" << "  "
         << setw(30) << left << "AUTHOR" << "   "
         << setw(6) << left << "PRICE" << "  "
         << "QTY"
         << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
      const Setting &book = books[i];

      // Only output the record if all of the expected fields are present.
      string title, author;
      double price;
      int qty;

      if(!(book.lookupValue("title", title)
           && book.lookupValue("author", author)
           && book.lookupValue("price", price)
           && book.lookupValue("qty", qty)))
        continue;

      cout << setw(30) << left << title << "  "
           << setw(30) << left << author << "  "
           << '$' << setw(6) << right << price << "  "
           << qty
           << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  catch(const SettingNotFoundException &nfex)
  {
    // Ignore.
  }

  // Output a list of all books in the inventory.
  try
  {
    const Setting &movies = root["inventory"]["movies"];
    int count = movies.getLength();

    cout << setw(30) << left << "TITLE" << "  "
         << setw(10) << left << "MEDIA" << "   "
         << setw(6) << left << "PRICE" << "  "
         << "QTY"
         << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
      const Setting &movie = movies[i];

      // Only output the record if all of the expected fields are present.
      string title, media;
      double price;
      int qty;

      if(!(movie.lookupValue("title", title)
           && movie.lookupValue("media", media)
           && movie.lookupValue("price", price)
           && movie.lookupValue("qty", qty)))
        continue;

      cout << setw(30) << left << title << "  "
           << setw(10) << left << media << "  "
           << '$' << setw(6) << right << price << "  "
           << qty
           << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  catch(const SettingNotFoundException &nfex)
  {
    // Ignore.
  }

  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

// eof
```

example.cfg

```
// An example configuration file that stores information about a store.

// Basic store information:
name = "Books, Movies & More";

// Store inventory:
inventory =
{
  books = ( { title  = "Treasure Island";
              author = "Robert Louis Stevenson";
              price  = 29.99;
              qty    = 5; },
            { title  = "Snow Crash";
              author = "Neal Stephenson";
              price  = 9.99;
              qty    = 8; }
          );

  movies = ( { title = "Brazil";
               media = "DVD";
               price = 19.99;
               qty = 11; },
             { title = "The City of Lost Children";
               media = "DVD";
               price = 18.99;
               qty = 5; },
             { title = "Memento";
               media = "Blu-Ray";
               price = 24.99;
               qty = 20;
             },
             { title = "Howard the Duck"; }
           );
};

// Store hours:
hours =
{
  mon = { open =  9; close = 18; };
  tue = { open =  9; close = 18; };
  wed = { open =  9; close = 18; };
  thu = { open =  9; close = 18; };
  fri = { open =  9; close = 20; };
  sat = { open =  9; close = 20; };
  sun = { open = 11; close = 16; };
};
```

Comment: Check your `LIBRARY_PATH` and where the libraries of the installed libgconfig actually went.

Comment: dpkg -L libconfig++9v5 
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libconfig++9v5
/usr/share/doc/libconfig++9v5/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libconfig++9v5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconfig++.so.9.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconfig++.so.9

Comment: `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?